# Common Initializer for Objective-C Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I've been programming in Objective-C for years now, and I always bump into this problem: If you have an object with multiple initializers, but there is code in common to all of them, how do you extract it out?

The best I've been able to come up with is something like this:

```
@implementation Example

- (void)privateInitWithString:(NSString*)aString
{
  self.str = aString;
}

- (id)init
{
  self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"MyNib"]
  if(self) {
    [self privateInitWithString:@""];
  }
  return self;
}

- (id)initWithString:(NSString*)aString
{
  self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"MyNib"]
  if(self) {
    [self privateInitWithString:aString];
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

There is a lot of duplication in the individual initializers which a code smell. However I can't think of a way to get one initializer to "fall through" to another one because there is no guarantee that `self` has been set before calling `[super init]`

Is there a best practice for this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You write *one* "designated initialiser". That initialiser handles all the different situations. In your case, initWithString seems a good candidate. And init just becomes

```
- (instancetype)init { return [self initWithString:@""]; }
```

You can read more about it here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html

Comment: +1 the technically correct answer, although there are a couple of scenarios where you can have *multiple* designated initializers, such as if you make your class conform to `<NSCoding>` (or sometimes `<NSCopying>`).

Comment: That's perfect! Here's a link to the section titled "Multiple Initializers and the Designated Initializer" at the bottom of the page: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW3